# C# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to UnityEngine.UI.Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error in my console: **Assets/Scripts/ScoreScript.cs(37,25): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to UnityEngine.UI.Text**

Here's my code:

```
public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int score = 0;
    public Text scoreText;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Score")
        {
            scoreText.text = (++score).ToString();
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            return;
        }
        else if (collision.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
            scoreText = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scoreText` is a `Text`, yet you're trying to assign a number to it.

Comment: You're already doing it correctly at `scoreText.text = (++score).ToString()`. Just do the same thing below it where `scoreText.text = 0`

Comment: Please only include releavent code. Also, with Unity, having `Start` and `Update` methods that do nothing are needless preformance hits. Unity won't call those methods on those GameObjects if they're not defined, so you can save on preformance by not writing them if they're not gonna be doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line here:

```
scoreText = 0;
```

To:

```
scoreText.text = 0.ToString();
```

Comment: As @Amy said above in the comments, `scoreText` is a `UI.Text` object of `Unity`, it can't be assigned an integer value, you need to set it's `.text` property to the integer  value converted to string.

Comment: That worked, thanks. But now, when my character dies and respawns, the score resets to zero which is what I want but when I hit the obstacle that's supposed to increase my score by 1, it increases it by 2. Then when my character respawns for the third time it increases my score from 0 to 3. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Hanaan328 You need to reset the `score` value to 0. Currently you're just setting the `scoreText = 0`, but the `score` is still holding onto whatever they had before they died. So when you say `scoreText = (++score)` it will add 1 to what they had before.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to fix it? I'm a noob at C Sharp sorry

Comment: Add this line `score = 0;` into the `if (collision.tag == "Obstacle")`

Comment: Ah that worked. Thanks so much guys! Stack Overflow is much more helpful than Unity Answers. Over there when you post a question some Mr. know it all shows up and says how easy the problem is and deletes the question without even answering it lol/

Comment: @Hanaan328 I'm glad you're finding Stack Overflow useful. However, you seem to have very limited knowledge of fundamental programming techniques. I suggest taking a short course on C# and how Object Orientated Programming works before continuing with building a game in Unity.